# Need help with a determinant problem

Tags: matrices, functions, determinant

I'm learning determinants and just came across a problem. I've been trying really hard to solve it but no success so far. I just know that the answer is (3) 1 but don't know how to solve it? Please explain in details.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about where you get stuck?  Have you computed the determinant for example?

Comment: Well I just don't know where to start. I mean the first step that I do is replace all the f(n) with (a^n +b^n). After that what to do next?

Comment: Compute the determinant!  It's a $3\times 3$ matrix and you can look up how to compute that [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Determinant-of-a-3X3-Matrix).  With some re-arranging you should be able to compare to $K(1-\alpha)^2(1-\beta)^2(\alpha-\beta)^2$ and work out $K$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I already know hos to compute a determinant but the calculation becomes too lengthy  . The problem is that I'm preparing for a time based exam and I cannot afford to spend so much time on just one problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$\scriptsize\begin{vmatrix}
3&1+a+b&1+a^2+b^2\\
1+a+b&1+a^2+b^2&1+a^3+b^3\\
1+a^2+b^2&1+a^3+b^3&1+a^4+b^4
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&a&b\\
1&a^2&b^2
\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&a&a^2\\
1&b&b^2
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&a&b\\
1&a^2&b^2
\end{vmatrix}^2=[(a-1)(b-1)(a-b)]^2$$

Comment: That's it. That's what I was looking for. But can you explain how did you separate the determinant into 2 determinants?

Comment: @Shashank with some thinking

Comment: Please explain it. I really need to know. Please!!!

Comment: @Shashank _yeh question pehle kar chuka hoon, isliye pata hai.Haan tab mereko bhi nahi aaya tha_

Comment: Solution mere pass bhi h yaar lekin mujhe bas yehi wala step samaj me nhi aa rha h

Comment: @Shashank _class mein ek bar pehle bataya to hoga sar ne, mereko bhi ser ne bataya tha, maine khud nahi soch paya tha, ek bar multiply karke dekh le, samajh aa jayega, phir do-tin bar bina dekhe ulta likh ke dekh(matlab det. ko tod ke dekh)_

Comment: @ Shashank ): If you practice more more & more then these types of thinking will come in your head automatically.. you also can do it..

Comment: @Panja.S. (i) you don't need to tag someone on their own post/ it's automatic (ii) I hadn't explained anything as such, BTW what's your language. (iii) I agree with Panja.S

Comment: @Panja.S. somewhat, met many Kolkattan's when I went for KVPY Camp to Kolkatta and very few from TV :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21730/discussion-between-adg-and-panja-s).